# Open soft keyboard programmatically as an overdraw over the views in the layout

Tags: java, android, layout, intellij-idea

I want to open the soft keyboard in such a way that it doesn't resize/move the existing views in the layout but gets drawn over them - *however*, I don't want this always to be the case for the activity. In other words, I can't set this in the Manifest - it needs to be set programmatically for a specific case of ime open in the activity. How can I do this?

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.something_here_maybe?);
        imm.showSoftInput(someView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING.  Please note this will cause no panning at all-  if the cursor is underneath where the keyboard wants to go it won't be moved and the user will be unable to see what he's typing.  Its not a recommended mode unless you're using the keyboard for something other than typing.